# Rspec testing strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have code completed a project almost 50%, but haven't written any test code. I want to write rspec, capybara tests. Now this is reverse of what actually is done in testing. What should be my strategy here from where should I start (from model, controller, feature) and what should be my approach. Also are there any tutorials for this

Comment: You can start writing the specs at any stage of your project development. I would say initially you can start writing the specs for your core logics, and you will be knowing where you have added your core logics and you can move on further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually it's better to start from feature tests. They are easier to write and they provide most of coverage because cover a lot of functionality at once.
Also you will need not so many feature tests comparing to unit tests, for example. Because they are on top of the [Testing Pyramid](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html)

When you will achieve decent coverage you can start throwing in unit test and refactor your codebase. Having feature tests you can eliminate the fear of refactoring. As soon as you haven't write test before the code your methods would be probably hard to test without additional refactoring.
That's is an additional advantage of having feature tests before unit tests.

You can find bunch of articles describing how do people usually test their projects.

As an example here is an article from Thoughtbot  https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-we-test-rails-applications

I would also recommend the [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052) book. 
It describes how to start covering projects with tests and then refactor the parts.

Comment: i started with writing model spec then i thought this is pointless because basically i was writing spec based my already created model.Thanks i will start feature specs.